# Does Katalon Studio works on Windows Server 2012 R2 standard?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

Katalon Studio is not working on Windows Server 2012 R2 standard while installing Win App Driver for Desktop Application Automaton it states it is only supported for Windows 10, Windows Server 2016 or higher can anyone support for the same

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Katalon Studio is not supported on Windows Server 2012, as stated by this [thread](https://forum.katalon.com/t/is-katalon-able-to-run-in-windows-server-2012/13009), but is supported on Windows Server 2016.

This might not be clear from [OS Requirements](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/getting-started.html), at first glance.